# Can I pass a text selection to Sublime's build system's arguments?

Tags: sublimetext3, build-system

I have unit tests in my code which I can tag with labels so I can run a subset of all my tests. Eg.:

```
$ ./tests '[pizza-tests]'"
```

Will run all tests marked with `pizza-tests`.

My Sublime build system looks something like this:

```
{
  ...
  "shell_cmd": "./build-project && ./tests '[pizza-tests]'"
  ...
}
```

Lets say I now select some text with my mouse in Sublime's code view. Can I somehow pass this selection to my build command?

(Would be handy because then I could select a specific test label and then hit CMD + B to run it)

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by implementing a custom build command using a sublime plugin. The plugin can expand custom variables inside the build command.  In this example, the custom command is named `shell_cmd_sel`:

```
{
  ...
  "shell_cmd_sel": "./build-project && ./tests '$SELECTION'"
  ...
}
```

See full implementation and explaination at the [Sublime forum thread](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/build-system-only-marked-text/37323)